# Is there a full list of Kubernetes controller names inside the kube-system namespace that are owned by Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, eks

I am aware that there is a kube-system namespace, and users are not expected to modify or create any objects in this namespace as it is not intended for user use. However, I would like to verify this in our system.

Is there a full list of Kubernetes controller names inside the kube-system namespace that are owned by Kubernetes, such as kube-dns and kube-proxy? Something like an official Kubernetes document related to this issue.